# Is there any way I can tell from what class/method a method is called?

Tags: objective-c, swift, c-preprocessor

I have a preprocessor macro that I use like this:

```
@implementation MyClass
- (void)methodA
{
    MyLog("Hello, method A!");
}

- (void)methodB
{
    MyLog("Hello, method %@!", @"B");
}
@end
```

And after macro expansion it looks like:

```
@implementation MyClass
- (void)methodA
{
    ; NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s - %@", __func__, "Hello, method A!"]); ;
}

- (void)methodB
{
    ; NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s - %@", __func__, "Hello, method %@!"], @"B"); ;
}
@end
```

This will result in these being printed for their respective methods:

> ```
> -[MyClass methodA] - Hello, method A!
> -[MyClass methodB] - Hello, method B!
> ```

I want to change this to a set of Objective-C **or Swift** methods, which I can call the same way and would give me the same result. I don't want to manage an object, so these should be class/static methods. **Is it possible to tell that I'm in a particular class/method and only use a particular log prefix while in there?**

If not, **is there any other way to use methods to mimic the behavior I achieved with the macros?**

Comment: try looking **[here (objective-c)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687785/any-way-to-ask-a-method-for-its-name/2687873#2687873)**, you should find what you are looking for (unless i misunderstood).  You could define macros to to this automagically depending on your build context (debug vs distro).

Comment: What the hell is with the semi colons? Don't do that.

Comment: @AMomchilov those are Due to the fact that the macros have, within them, a semicolon before and after their statement (to guard against expansion syntax mishaps; the same reason `do { ... } while(0)` is used). So, when I type out the macro with a semicolon after it, all three appear in the expanded form.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Seems to just print out the log method's name :P

Comment: @YvesLeBorg correct, but with the nice, terse expression I was able to achieve with the preprocessor macros

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware that code was after marcro expansion, my bad

Comment: Maybe useful [`NSThread.callStackSymbols `](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/callStackSymbols)

Answer (score 2):

Generally the Swift tool you want here is `#function`. For example:

```
func MyLog(msg: String, function: StaticString = #function) {
    print("\(function) - \(msg)")
}
```

`#function`, when used as a default parameter value, evaluates to the function that at the calling site. Since it's a default value, you don't have to pass a `function` parameter.

This is not compatible with ObjC, however. For that, you'll still need macros. If you want to forward along an ObjC macro to Swift, you'd do something like:

```
#define MYLog(message) [Log log:message function:@(__FUNCTION__)]
```

You'd then need to write `MyLog` this way:

```
struct Log {
    static func log(msg: String, function: String = #function) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It has to be in a `struct` to be accessible to ObjC (or it could be an enum), and you have to make `function` of type `String` rather than `StaticString` because ObjC can't generate `StaticString`.

Build like this, in Swift, you would call:

```
Log.log("my message")
```

and in ObjC you would call

```
MyLog("my message")
```

Comment: This looks amazing. I'm not clear on one thing, though; will it be possible to actually call `MyLog` from ObjC? If so, how?

Comment: Sorry; my original code there was a weird ObjC/Swift nonsense hybrid. Fixed.

Comment: @RobNapier: this is great! I didn't know this technique.

Comment: Awesome; I'll try this out the first moment I can

Answer (score 0):

I produce (by macro expansion) a similar result.

In GERuntimeConstants.h, i define

```
extern void QuietLog(NSString *format, ...);
```

in GERuntimeConstants.m, i provide QuietLog as :

```
void QuietLog(NSString *format, ...) {

    if (format == nil) {
        printf("nil\n");
        return;
    }
    // Get a reference to the arguments that follow the format parameter
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, format);
    // Perform format string argument substitution, reinstate %% escapes, then print
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:argList];
    printf("%s\n", [[s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%%" withString:@"%%%%"] UTF8String]);
    va_end(argList);
}
```

in GEMacros, i define

```
#define __MPLOGWITHFUNCTION(s, ...) \
QuietLog(@"%s : %@",__FUNCTION__,[NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__])  
#define MPLOG(...) __MPLOGWITHFUNCTION(__VA_ARGS__)
```

I include GEMacros.h in my .pch

anywhere i want to log , i would have a single line of code that looks like the following example :

```
- (void)cleanupWithError:(NSString *)status message:(NSString *)message {
      MPLOG(@"*** Cleaning up , status[%@], message[%@]",status,message);
```

and this statement translates to this in the console :

```
-[EHRCall cleanupWithError:message:] : *** Cleaning up , status[INVALID_PARAMETERS], message[No api user with api key [patient01ApiKey]]
```

So in my code, i use MPLOG as NSLog (always).  The definition via _MPLOGWITHFUNCTION is because I have other macros that are tuned to the build. This definition is for logging while working a debug build. For distro MPLOG defines down to `;`.

Comment: ah, missed that ... i wont debate that for sure. I am lazy by nature, and like to be able to change one compilation flag to flip some of my `throw-away` code (like logging).

Comment: That certainly is a wonderful feature of C. However, we're trying to move our code to be Swift-compatible, if not just Swift.