# NSLog the method name with Objective-C in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, c, iphone, debugging

Currently, we are defining ourselves an extended log mechanism to print out the class name and the source line number of the log.

```
#define NCLog(s, ...) NSLog(@"<%@:%d> %@", [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], \
    __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__])
```

For example, when I call NCLog(@"Hello world");
The output will be:

```
<ApplicationDelegate:10>Hello world
```

Now I also want to log out the method name like:

```
<ApplicationDelegate:applicationDidFinishLaunching:10>Hello world
```

So, this would make our debugging become easier when we can know which method is getting called. I know that we also have Xcode debugger but sometimes, I also want to do debugging by logging out.

Comment: In my last `iPhone` project, I actually did this manually. Would love to see the answer to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/how-to-print-out-the-method-name-and-line-number-and-conditionally-disable-nslog

Answer (score 274, accepted):

```
print(__FUNCTION__) // Swift
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)); // Objective-C
```

**Swift 3 and above**

```
print(#function)
```

Comment: You really should use `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd))`, if you're going to use `_cmd`, since AFAIK Apple declares `_cmd` as type `SEL`, not a C-string. Just because it happens to be implemented as a C-string (as of the current versions of Mac OS X and the iPhone OS) doesn't mean you should use it in that way, since Apple could change it in an OS update.

Comment: Yes, NSStringFromSelector is the more correct answer.  I never use _cmd as c string for anything but debug code.

Comment: Wow, the compiler complaints about pointer incompatibility, but it works... So _cmd (type: SEL) **really is** a char* !?

Comment: Method calls like `[self doSomething:arg1 somethingElse:arg2]` get converted into the C function call `objc_msgSend(self, "doSomething:somethingElse:, arg1, arg2);`. The second parameter of `objc_msgSend()` takes a `char*`. Remember that because the Objective-C runtime is dynamic, it's actually using a lookup table to figure out which method on which class to call so a char* is convenient since methods are represented as strings in the lookup table.

Comment: For Swift 2.2 should use `print("\(#function)")`

Answer (score 165):

To technically answer your question, you want:

```
NSLog(@"<%@:%@:%d>", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), __LINE__);
```

Or you could also do:

```
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

Comment: With `__FUNCTION__` and its pretty equivalent also being available in C-functions.

Comment: N.B. `__FUNCTION__` also includes the class name

Comment: is there any difference using     NSLog(@"%s",**__func__**); OR NSLog(@"%s", **__PRETTY_FUNCTION__**)  ???

Answer (score 86):

## tl;dr

```
NSLog( @"ERROR %@ METHOD %s:%d ", @"DescriptionGoesHere", __func__, __LINE__ );
```

## Details

Apple has a Technical Q&A page: [QA1669 - How can I add context information - such as the current method or line number - to my logging statements?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1669/_index.html)

To assist with logging:

- The C preprocessor provides a few **macros**.
- Objective-C provides **expressions** (methods).

  - Pass the **implicit argument** for the current method's selector: `_cmd`

As other answers indicated, to merely get the current method's name, call:

```
NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)
```

To get the current method name *and* current line number, use these two macros `__func__` and `__LINE__` as seen here:

```
NSLog(@"%s:%d someObject=%@", __func__, __LINE__, someObject);
```

Another example… Snippets of code I keep in Xcode's Code Snippet Library:

```
NSLog( @"ERROR %@ METHOD %s:%d ", @"DescriptionGoesHere", __func__, __LINE__ );
```

…and TRACE instead of ERROR…

```
NSLog( @"TRACE %@ METHOD %s:%d ", @"DescriptionGoesHere", __func__, __LINE__ );
```

…and a longer one using a soft-coded description passing a value (`[rows count]`)…

```
NSLog( @"TRACE %@ METHOD %s:%d.", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'Table of Contents.txt' file's count of Linefeed-delimited rows: %u.", [rows count]] , __func__, __LINE__ );
```

## Preprocessor macros for logging

Note the use of a **pair of underscore** characters around both sides of the macro.

```
| Macro                | Format   | Description
  __func__               %s         Current function signature
  __LINE__               %d         Current line number
  __FILE__               %s         Full path to source file
  __PRETTY_FUNCTION__    %s         Like __func__, but includes verbose
                                    type information in C++ code.
```

## Expressions for logging

```
| Expression                       | Format   | Description
  NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)         %@         Name of the current selector
  NSStringFromClass([self class])    %@         Current object's class name
  [[NSString                         %@         Source code file name
    stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__]   
    lastPathComponent] 
  [NSThread callStackSymbols]        %@         NSArray of stack trace
```

---

### Logging Frameworks

Some logging frameworks may help with getting current method or line number as well. I'm not sure, as I've used a great logging framework in Java ([SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) + [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/)) but not Cocoa.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926320/best-logger-for-cocoa) for links to various Cocoa logging frameworks.

### Name of Selector

If you have a Selector variable (a [SEL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Selector.html)), you can print its method name ("message") in either of two ways as described by this *Codec* [blog post](http://www.trembl.org/codec/484/):

- Using Objective-C call to [NSStringFromSelector](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromSelector):
  `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(selector) );`
- Using straight C:
  `NSLog(@"%s", selector );`

---

This information drawn from the linked Apple doc page as of 2013-07-19. That page had been last updated 2011-10-04.

Comment: For C, use `sel_getName(SEL)` since SEL is an opaque type and might not always be a `char *`

Answer (score 8):

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)); // Objective-C
print(__FUNCTION__) // Swift
```

Comment: For anyone who comes across this answer in the future: it is equivalent to the accepted answer, but the accepted answer was different, when this one was posted (the accepted answer was edited in 2014). I was about to down vote, but after a small investigation up voted instead :)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually just as simple as:

```
printf(_cmd);
```

For some reason iOS allows _cmd to be passed as a literal char with not even a compile warning. Who knows

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4:

func test(){

```
print(#function)
```

}

test() //print the value "test()"