# Print out the variable name objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging

Continued from the last question here: [Log method name in Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770307/log-the-method-name-in-objective-c) . I just wondered if there is a way to print out the variable name as well. For example:

```
NSString *name = "vodkhang";
NCLog(@"%@", name);
```

and I hope that the output should be:

```
name: vodkhang
```

Just to summarize the previous post, currently, I can print out the class name, method name and the line number when I call

```
NCLog(@"Hello World");
<ApplicationDelegate:applicationDidFinishLaunching:10>Hello world
```

with

```
#define NCLog(s, ...) NSLog(@"<%@:%d> %@", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__])
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
#define logIntVariable(x) NSLog( @"Value of %s = %d",#x, x)


- (void) myRoutine {
   int intValue = 5;

   logIntVariable(intValue);
}
```

Comment: The general principle is that when you put a `#` in front of an argument within the body of a `#define`, the preprocessor replaces it with a C string of the *exact* expression passed to the macro. When you pass a variable name, you'll get that name. If you pass an expression, it will reproduce the expression in full, not the evaluated result.