# Get Variable Name of Component

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, self

I am creating a listener application that attaches to my app and prints to the console, `Variable: "name"` when the user taps on a certain component, such as `Variable: button` if the user taps on a UIButton with the title "button".

I am stuck on UIImagePickerControllers. Does anyone know how to get the variable name, ie, the name used to created the UIImagePicker `(UIImagePickerController *imagePicker)` if I have that stored as a "self" variable.

Such as, when I do `NSLog(@"%@", self);` it prints "`<UIImagePickerController: 0x8342700>`"

How can I get it to print `imagePicker`, (the variable name)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/q/2818542/767730

Comment: @Anupdas It doesn't seem like that could help me but I may be wrong.

Comment: I have given an answer which worked after modifying the above mentioned answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818585/767730)

```
#define NSLogVariable(x) NSLog( @"Variable : %s",#x)
```

From code

```
NSLogVariable(imagePicker);
```

Comment: This won't work because when I call it, I am using the "self" variable. So when I do NSLogVariable(self); It prints: Variable: self

Comment: When you are giving self, the variable name is "self". Waiting for a proper answer.

Comment: But self is, <UIImagePickerController: 0x8342700>, and in my native app "self" is declared as UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;

Comment: I don't know how it will resolve variable name "imagePicker" as the memory of the object pickerController can be pointed by any number of variables.

Comment: Henry, self is a special variable passed into call Objective-C methods referring to the object that owns it. It isn't declared as anything special, other than id self in the method arguments. You don't see this argument as they are automatically added by the compiler for you. Another such special variable is the _cmd variable, which is also added to your method arguments automatically.