# Print out a variable name

Tags: iphone, ios, variables, nslog, currentlocation

I am finding the closest location to my current location and I'd like to `NSLog` the closest `CLLocation` variable name instead of it's value.

How would I go about doing this? This is how I get the value of the longitude and latitude of the variable:

`NSLog(@"the closest location is %@", closestLocation);`

For example, I would want it to say: "the closest location is Starbucks (the variable name)" instead of "the closest location is LONGITUDE, LATITUDE".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818542/print-out-the-variable-name-objective-c

Comment: @Saikat Checked that out. I believe that has a different purpose. Can you explain it with my code?

Comment: The purpose seems exactly the same to me.  You want to NSLog the variable name right?  That's what the code in the link does.

Comment: @borrrden As a beginner, I do not understand. Will you explain? How would I do that with my code?

Comment: @user the question is a bit confusing now to me. Do you want the name of a place given it's lat/lng? If so, checkout http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Saikat yes. Just to print out the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are spot on, but since you don't see the connection I'll try to make it clear:

```
#define LogTheLocationVariable(x) NSLog(@"The variable is %s", #x)
```

Now you can use the macro:

```
LogTheLocationVariable(closestLocation);
```

And you'll get:

```
The variable is closestLocation
```