# Best Logger for cocoa

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios, logging

Can anyone recommend me a good logger for cocoa, something that should be in par with log4j.

I've been developing this app in cocoa & as the source code is growing I find my self craving for a logger. I've googled a bit, have found a few options but I am looking to hear from you guys & your experiences with these loggers.

I look forward to hearing your comments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apple System Logger is the OS X logging system. The best introuction is Peter Hosey's series of [blogs](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/category/programming/apple-system-logger) on the subject. The ASL is accessed via a C API, but it's not difficult to wrap in Objective-C. I've given up my homespun wrapper in favor of the `GTMLogger` facility in [Google's Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/), which includes ASL support.

Answer (score 16):

Here are a few options for you:

- [ASLogger](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/tree/master/ASLogger/)
- [CLCLog](http://code.google.com/p/cola-framework/source/browse/trunk/CoLa/CLCLog.h)
- [GTMLogger](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMLogger.h)
- [Lumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack)
- [NSLogger](http://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger)