# Which are free available good logging framework for cocoa environment?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nslog

As of now I use NSLog for logging from my OS X application. But NSLog gives me no control over log level, size and number of log files. Other problem I face with NSLog is even though I redirect log statements to a file, I still see entries in System log (using console).

I found a logging framework [log4cocoa](http://log4cocoa.sourceforge.net/), but this looks very old. Before making decision and start using log4cocoa, I want to know which all free logging frameworks are available for cocoa and merits / demerits of those.

Update: I also found one more logging framework called [lumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack). I am gonna try these two and see how they fair

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Best Logger for cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926320/best-logger-for-cocoa) answers too.

Comment: This link gives details about almost all available solutions.

Answer (score 6):

OS X includes a built-in logging facility, the Apple System Logger (ASL). ASL supports multiple output streams, and logging levels.

Peter Hosey's [series](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2008-01-20/why-asl) on the ASL is still the best introduction to the system and its API. The ASL API is in C, but it's quite easy to write an Objective-C wrapper and some preprocessor macros to make your life easier. The [Google Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/) has the `GTMLogger` class that supports flat-file, stdout, and ASL (via the GTMLogger+ASL category). If you don't mind taking an additional dependency, I would use GTM and its `GTMLogger` facilities.

Comment: +1 for nice information. I also found one more logging framework called [lumberjack](http://code.google.com/p/cocoalumberjack/). I am gonna try these two and see how they fair.

Comment: Updated URL: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack