# How do I get the method name at compile time?

Tags: java, reflection, macros, compile-time

How do I get the enclosing method name at compile time?

And why has it been difficult for me to figure this out?  Why wouldn't Java want me to do this? I don't see any inherent problems with a feature like this, and it's useful for logging method names without duplication between the method signature and the string constant like so:

```
private void methodName() {
   final String MN = "methodName";
   ...
```

Someone might change the method name without changing the MN constant, and then I can't find it in the log.

I know Java has a (reflective?) method for doing this, but why anyone would want to over-complicate things and create the possibility of errors with a run-time solution (for this particular problem) is beyond me.

Apparently macros are bad practice, but I think this is a pretty good use case for them.  That's what I'm basically going for, something like a macro, a constant.

Btw, this question is pretty similar:

[Getting the name of the current executing method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method)

None of the solutions are constants derived at compile time, though.  They're all run-time computations.

---

EDIT: Why can't it be done at compile time?

Please don't give a trivial answer like "that's the way Java was designed", because then I'll just ask "why ?"

Comment: *What* method name? Please explain more clearly what exactly you're trying to accomplish. (The answer may be that you need to use Java 8 method handles.)

Comment: If you use a logging framework, then capturing the method name is already taken care of.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the name of the current executing method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method)

Comment: i don't think it's a dupe, im looking for a compile time solution which is not mentioned in that one

Comment: Have you looked at *all* of the answers in the linked questions and verified that *all* of them are run-time?

Comment: If so, please edit your question to link to that question and mention that none of the answers there will work for your question because you are looking for a compile-time solution.

Comment: Can't be done at compile time.

Comment: There's no good reason why this can't be done since this could easily be done by a compiler or preprocessor. In fact, other languages support this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770307/nslog-the-method-name-with-objective-c-in-iphone

Answer (score 2):

From the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891326/4353712:

```
String name = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
```

However, as mentioned in the answer, this generates a new `.class` file every time you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Not at compile time, but still might work out for you:

```
public class test1 {
    public void display() {
        try {
            final String s = this.getClass().getMethod("display",null).toString();
            System.out.println(s);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        test1 obj = new test1();
        obj.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this any better than his solution? You still have to type the method name by hand...

Comment: From java docs, getEnclosingMethod() - If this Class object represents a local or anonymous class within a method, returns a Method object representing the immediately enclosing method of the underlying class. So as per my understanding, this works only if there exists a class within a method.

For my solution, you have to type the method name but you get a fully qualified name in return.
If you want to get name of the method on-the-fly then I dont think that is possible.