# Simpler NSLog macro

Tags: iphone

using iphone sdk 4.0 I want to remove the function name stuff from this macro but am struggling

```
#define LOG(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,##__VA_ARGS__)
```

i tried

```
#define LOG(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s " fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

but this results in a crash!!

I want to be able to log like this

```
LOG("text to log");
LOG("text to log with param %d", param); etc
```

Comment: Use these [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/nslog-tips-and-tricks/969291#969291)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not simply like this ?

```
#define LOG(fmt, ...) NSLog(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this

```
#define Log(fmt, ...) NSLog(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

Comment: already tried that,it  doesn't work as i already have all my log statements

LOG("some text"); ie without the @

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your log macro in a do{ }while(0); statement to avoid possibility of errors with if statements

see

[do { ... } while (0) — what is it good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for)