# iphone mapkit application performing local business searches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

Developing iphone application using makkit framework. I have got the map view integrated in the application. Wanted some help regarding performing search in a region (local search) using some api , I have tried exploring google java-script API and ajax api but cannot pin point my solution any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a partial bit of code that I used for the google search APIs.
You will need to visit Google Labs API and get a key you can use for search.
There is also a GData library, but I had trouble getting it to work for local search so I just went with the HTML/JSON version. 
My code shows you how to start to decode the JSON that is returned, I cut off the loop since it does a bunch of other stuff.

This is the link to the [Google AJAX APi](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/).

I recommend making the API call and then setting a breakpoint where you can look at the dictionary of JSON results you get back to see how it's structured.

```
NSString *searchString = 
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&sll=%f,%f&q=%@", 
         currentLocation.establishedLocation.coordinate.latitude,
         currentLocation.establishedLocation.coordinate.longitude, 
         searchTerms];
        searchString = [searchString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  // encode it
        //NSString *localSearchResults = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchString]];
        NSError *error = nil;

        NSString * localSearchResults = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error retrieving map search results in ActivityLocationViewControler::lookupSearchTerms: ");    
            NSLog(@"%s %d %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FUNCTION__);   // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/nslog-tips-and-tricks/969272
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }  


        else {

            NSData *jsonData = [localSearchResults dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];    

            // we now magically have an array of results from our search.  Each result has a bunch of data.
            NSArray *resultsArray =  [[dictionary objectForKey:@"responseData"] objectForKey:@"results"] ;
            //NSArray *resultsArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"responseData"];

            CLLocationCoordinate2D curCoordinate;
            NSDictionary *currentResult;
            BOOL skipThisEntry;

            for (int i = 0; i < [resultsArray count]; i++) {
                currentResult = [resultsArray objectAtIndex:i];     // this is a dictionary of this result

                curCoordinate.latitude = [(NSString *) [currentResult objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue] ;
                curCoordinate.longitude = [(NSString *) [currentResult objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just published some simple iOS classes that use Google's Local Search API to get location information about places in a map region via a name or address search. There are [detailed instructions here](http://www.totagogo.com/2011/02/08/google-local-search-ios-code/), and [the GitHub repository is here](https://github.com/vvanhee/Google-Local-Search-iOS).

Hopefully, this information will make it very easy for new developers to use the Google Local API in an iPhone app to get the latitude & longitude of businesses & other places.

Answer (score 0):

MapKit provides the MKLocalSearch API.

We can use this API to perform searches for locations that users describe by name, address, or type, such as coffee or theater.

For reference:

```
// Create and initialize a search request object.
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText;
request.region = self.map.region;

// Create and initialize a search object.
MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

// Start the search and display the results as annotations on the map.
[search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error)
 {
     NSMutableArray *placemarks = [NSMutableArray array];
     for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems) {
         [placemarks addObject:item.placemark];
         //For Address
         //NSDictionary *addressDict = item.placemark.addressDictionary;
     }
     [self.map removeAnnotations:[self.map annotations]];
     [self.map showAnnotations:placemarks animated:NO];
 }];
```