# Do I have alternatives to using NSLog to debug object values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is NSLog the best way to debug the value of variables during execution?  I find that navigating into the object doesn't show me what I want to see and I find I have to NSLog all over my application.

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/nslog-tips-and-tricks/1675434)

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DLog( s, ... ) NSLog( @"<%p %@:(%d)> %@", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__] )
#else
#define DLog( s, ... ) 
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a debugger, too.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this didn't fit as a comment, couldn't format it.

I find that __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ does a nice job.  It tells the class and method name.

```
#define PLog(fmt, ...) NSLog(@"%s L%d %@", \__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, \__LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__]);
```