# How to clear NSLog output from code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

is there a way to clear console output from code?

thanks.

Comment: You could delete the log file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHORTCUT I PREFER :

Simply USE <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> Keyboard Shortcut when you want to clear the NSLOG Data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do that in code.

Though there is an option in XCode preferences (*Debugging tab*) called *Auto Clear Debug Console*. It will clear console output each time you run the application. That might fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you search the site, you will find [several way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/nslog-tips-and-tricks)s of manipulating NSLog. I use

```
#ifndef __OPTIMIZE__
#    define NSLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#    define NSLog(...) {}
#endif
```

to kill the output. Put the above in your .pch file in your 'Other Sources' folder and it works out of the box for release builds. Replace OPTIMIZE with some other preprocessing flag if you want this to work for other build configurations.