# clear logs generated by NSlog from consol by code

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, nslog

I want to clear logs from consol by coding like we are using `clrscr()` in c language
I am working on a navigation based application this application has too much logs generated by NSLog. When i feel that the code is working fine till now, i want to clear logs.

I got a solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701703/is-there-any-way-to-clear-nslog-output) but this solution adds `\n` in the logs and i want to clear it completely so if you have any other solution please share with me.

thanks in advance i am waiting for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe its possible to clear the console from inside your application.. However if you are developing in XCode, just click in the console output window and press cmd k - this will clear all of the scrollback...

Alternatively - just disable the logging / wrap the nslog calls in another method that limits how much is displayed