# #define NSLog (...) still print output to the console

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nslog

I tried to disable NSLog in release build.

I put the following code in .pch file

> #ifndef __OPTIMIZE__
>   #    define NSLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
>   #else
>   #    define NSLog(...) {}
>   #endif

It's not working, so I tried

> #    define NSLog(...) {}

It still prints output to the console.

Any help will be good, thanks!

Comment: You should probably switch on `NDEBUG`, and not `__OPTIMIZE__`.

Answer (score 1):

you would declare your own log function and use that instead. its implementation could go through NSLogv, if you want a va list. its implementation would also not forward the messages to NSLogv when disabled, so you will likely need more than one flavor of logger.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you want is similar to this definition for DLog from [this previous SO answer on NSLog tips and tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/nslog-tips-and-tricks/969291#969291).

```
#ifdef DEBUG 
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__); 
#else 
#   define DLog(...)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `__OPTIMIZE__` is defined in the build settings or higher up in the .pch file itself and that the pch file is set in the **Prefix Header** (GCC_PREFIX_HEADER) Build Settings. Also you can define NSLog(...) as nothing

`#define NSLog(...)`

Comment: Probably not best to define it out as nothing - this can cause unintended side effects in code, e.g., an if statement with a single NSLog following and no brackets...

Comment: Although I said good point I just realized that you still need a semicolon after the NSLog so `for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++);` is valid. Where it could cause an issue is using a comma in code. `int i;i=10,NSLog("i %d", i);`

Comment: {} do not work with the comma operator either o.O  `i=10,{};` = !Expected expression.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor macro set in Build Setting of project having: DEBUG=1 $(inherited)

So now just use : if(DEBUG) NSLog(@"Your log");

Answer (score 0):

In you application .pch file put following line.
define NSLog(dese,...)

It will stop printing.