# XCode – Upgraded to 4.2 from 4.0.2 and now my DEBUG #DEFINE doesn't work

Tags: xcode, debugging

I'm using a debug macro as defined in this post: [How to print out the method name and line number and conditionally disable NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/nslog-tips-and-tricks/969291#969291)

But now when I upgraded from XCode 4.0.2 to 4.2 all of a sudden there is no debugging output in the console. What happened?

In my App-Prefix.pch:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define DLog(...)
#endif
```

How I've been using it:

```
DLog(@"%@", variable);
```

And then I had a Preprocessor Macro for my Debug target that said `DEBUG_MODE=1`

Comment: Might need some code for this one please. Show us the `#define` and an example of where you use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just sounds as if your Preprocessor macro has been lost during the upgrade. Ensure that, in your build settings for your debug target, that `DEBUG_MODE=1` is set.