# Is there a good way to grab NSLogged information from an iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, debugging, nslog

I have an iPhone app that uses the user's location, and transit information, to display the arrivals of nearby trains. I have a bug in the code that I run into once or twice a week, and I'm having a hard time reproducing. I'm NSLogging relevant information, but the console logs only go back a few hours on my phone.

Does anyone know of a good tool or method to get log information further back than whats available on the iphone?

Should I just log to a file?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: You could redefine NSLog to log to a file pretty easily. Here's some great inspiration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/how-to-print-out-the-method-name-and-line-number-and-conditionally-disable-nslog

Comment: Or write your own logging classes that write to the documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the TestFlight SDK, you can use `TFLog` and the log will go back to the TestFlight server.