# Log line number and method name in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nslog

I am converting an `Objective C` code to `Swift`. Found out this code :

```
#define MPLog(fmt, ...) \
    do { \
        if ([MPPush getLoggingPref] && ![MPPush getEnvironmentPref]) { \
            NSLog(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
        } \
    } while(0)
```

I am aware what this code does but I am not able to convert this. I found [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/how-to-print-out-the-method-name-and-line-number-and-conditionally-disable-nslog) great link but this has only `Objective C` reference.

Comment: Try to convert it via this site: https://objectivec2swift.com/

Comment: @EmreÖnder : Did that. It just put comments in front of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift provides some expressions in order to log, among others line number and method name:

```
Literal     Type    Value
#file       String  The name of the file in which it appears.
#line       Int     The line number on which it appears.
#column     Int     The column number in which it begins.
#function   String  The name of the declaration in which it appears.
```

For example:

```
func logFunctionName(string: String = #function) {
    print(string)
}
func myFunction() {
    logFunctionName() // Prints "myFunction()".
}
```

For more information, check the [official documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID390)