# How to setup Xcodes "debug/release target settings"?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, macros, c-preprocessor

I have found a set of great macros here [Objective C Macros](http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/01/05/macros-for-xcode/)

I put the:

```
#if DEBUG==1
#define .... macros
```

in my header file.

Now I simply can't figure out where to set **DEBUG=1** or **DEBUG=0** in Xcode so that
it will define the macro when debugging and not when releasing.

Hope someone can help me find the missing drop down menu:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Ok apparently, when working on an iPhone application, you have to:

- select iPhone device as the active sdk
- then edit project or target settings and in "Other C Flags" you type "-DDEBUG=1"

---

Edit your project or target settings, select your `Debug` configuration then look for the "Preprocessor Macros" settings and type `DEBUG=1`

However, I would rather define `NDEBUG` in the `Release` configuration then write

```
#ifndef NDEBUG // if we are in debug mode
#define bla bla bla
#endif
```

Note: you need to have a target that compiles Objective-C source files to a library or application properly set up; otherwise  the settings don't appear in the UI.

Comment: Hi thanks guys.
I now went "Project" -> "Edit Project Settings" - "Build tab"  and under the header "Packaging" there was a "info.plist Preprocessor Definitions". I takes space separated values says the manual. I tried putting "DEBUG=1" here and then restart Xcode. But it does not work?
All the NSLog macros I try to use yields no output, but no warnings or errors either. It seems as if DEBUG=0 still.

Comment: Hi Gregory

Im compiling and debugging for the iPhone Simulator. Does this qualify?
If I omit the if... part it works just fine. Just seems I can't figure out where to define **DEBUG**.

Thanks again for your help

Comment: no it should be in the "GCC 4.0 Preprocessing" (or alike) section not "Packaging"

Comment: Thank you Gregory!
I work like a charm in both Simulator and Device. Not the most obvious path to get there though:) Thanks again for figuring it out.

Comment: Exactly, that's just awful, I was so surprised at first when I tried :) Have fun