# How to get Class name and method name while displaying a message in console using 'NSLog' in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have started a new project on iPad.I would like to know the method name and class name from which a particular message is sent to console while printing the message.Is there any way to print class & method names along with the log statement automatically.Please help and make my debugging easier thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@ %s", [self className], sel_getName(_cmd));
```

As `_cmd` starts with an underscore, it's potentially something you might not be able to rely on in the future, but everybody seems to use it for diagnostic logging.

Comment: but i dont want to include any formate in NSLog statement, except the actual information to be displayed

Comment: @Hariprasad: I'm not sure I understand.  The format specifiers I put in are necessary.  Obviously, you can do two NSLogs, one for each.

Comment: Suggest

    `NSLog(@"%@ %s", [self class], sel_getName(_cmd));`

as `className` message does not compute

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

P.S. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300673/is-it-true-that-one-should-not-use-nslog-on-production-code) may also be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The below is the way I used in my app

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([self class]));
```

Also see improved logging section in Apple documentation.
[Improved logging in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1669/_index.html)

-anoop

Answer (score 1):

If you want the classname as an NSString, use code below;

[[myObject class] description]