# NSLog with the release of the app

Tags: objective-c, nslog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it true that one should not use NSLog() on production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300673/is-it-true-that-one-should-not-use-nslog-on-production-code)

While a developer develops an app he/she is most likely using NSlogs these logs can be huge or small.. but will this make a big presentation difference for the app if you publish it in the appstore while you still have the `NSLog("something%i",[stuff]);` in your code.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case, you can add to your **.PCH** this line:

```
#define DEBUG YES
```

and call `NSLog` in this way:

```
if(DEBUG) NSLog(@"debug mode");
```

Remember to set `#define DEBUG NO` when publish your app!

Comment: If you are using Xcode 4 DEBUG is defined for development.If you use the release scheme DEBUG is already defined as NO, so there is no need to do this manually.

Comment: I use Xcode4 and DEBUG is only a define name, that not conflict with xcode4 debug mode. If it isn't you can call this define DEBUGG! :)

Comment: Again - no need for any of this. I just use these macros (https://gist.github.com/325926) in my .pch file and use the Xcode4 settings for Development and release.

Comment: Who's panicking? I'm just pointing out to anyone else reading this answer that manual definitions of DEBUG aren't necessary if they are using Xcode4.