# Compiler warning when trying to add #define DEBUG_MODE to my prefix.pch file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to figure out how to strip debug logging from my project when I build it for release and found an excellent thread here: [Is it true that one should not use NSLog() on production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300673/is-it-true-that-one-should-not-use-nslog-on-production-code/1484866#1484866)

A bit below the answer another user explained how to enable/disable the DEBUG_MODE definition, so I went in exactly as explained, i.e.

In the project settings, "preprocessor macros", debug row it already read "debug=1", so I added the "debug_mode=1" to the end of the string so that it now reads "debug=1 debugmode=1" (with an ${inherited} inbetween, whatever that is...)

However, I now get a compiler yellow warning saying:

Lexical or preprocessor issue, "DEBUG_MODE" macro redefined on the row in my prefix.pch file where I added:

```
#define DEBUG_MODE

#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    #define DebugLog( s, ... ) NSLog( @"<%p %@:(%d)> %@", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__] )
#else
#define DebugLog( s, ... ) 
#endif
```

If someone could explain this define issue i'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change it to:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define DebugLog( s, ... ) NSLog( @"<%p %@:(%d)> %@", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__] )
#else
    #define DebugLog( s, ... ) 
#endif
```

Remove the `#define DEBUG_MODE` and remove the `debugmode=1` from the "preprocessor macros"
and you are good to go.

The error you where getting was due to the `#define DEBUG_MODE` which was already defined in the "preprocessor macros".

Comment: Thanks man, that's what i did :) But i still don't understand what the warning means, is it possible for you to explain please?

Comment: This solution doesn't quite fix it for me. I have a set of "if elif elif elifs" and in one of the cases I redefine a value which is overriding a default setting defined at the top. ...If you see what I mean. The code looks clean and seems to compile and run perfectly, but annoyingly has this warning.