# Can ipa file be created in debug mode?

Tags: xcode, ipa

Two questions on ipa files.

- Can ipa file be created in debug mode? If so, how do you archive the file in debug mode?
- Our ipa file, after installed to a device, is outputting our logs to the console. Can we disable logging functionality to the console?

My environment Xcode 4.6 and iOS 5 & 6.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

About the first question, yes, you can archive an app in Debug mode. From Xcode, browse the *Product* menu, *Scheme*, *Manage Schemes*, *Edit*. Select the *Archive* action on the left pane and choose *Debug* as Build Configuration in the drop down box.

If you want to restrict logging only to Debug configurations, you can add this to your `ProjectName-Prefix.pch` file:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define XYZLog(format, ...) NSLog(format, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define XYZLog(format, ...)
#endif
```

Where "XYZ" is the three letter prefix for your application (Cocoa naming convention).

Then you must use `XYZLog` instead of `NSLog` in your code and the output will only go to the console for Debug versions.

Comment: I've got ERROR: Flutter archive builds must be run in Release mode.

Answer (score 1):

So to create a debuggable IPA, you will need to Archive it and save for Ad-Hoc or Enterprise.

As far as logging to the console in this ad-hoc build, there are several ways to do this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7692815/171206).