# How to find whether a given ipa is built in debug or release mode?

Tags: ios, ipa

I have an ipa file . How can I check whether that application is built in debug / release mode without the help of source code ? Do we have any checkpoints to find out ?

Answer (score -1):

So to create a debuggable IPA, you will need to Archive it and save for Ad-Hoc or Enterprise.

As far as logging to the console in this ad-hoc build, there are several ways to do this, [iPhone: Suppress NSLog in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692802/iphone-suppress-nslog-in-production/7692815#7692815)

Comment: Avinash651 , But I am having only ipa , But no source code . In that case can I find something in package contents ?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

The current version of Xcode automatically sets the DEBUG macro in new

projects. It does this only for Debug build mode however.

You can edit this in your projects Build Settings.

I recommend you add a new, separate macro instead of editing the DEBUG

one. Maybe you could add a DISTRIBUTION or DEPLOYMENT macro only for the

release mode.