# Objective-C equivalent of if(D)Log.w(TAG,"Message")

Tags: android, objective-c, logging, iphone-4

In my Android programs, I frequently used :

private static final boolean D = true;

Then all of my calls to Log were prepended with if(D)

```
if(D)Log.w("Tag", "message");
```

This helped easily clean up code by setting the D value to false to remove all logging.

2 Questions:
Do calls to "NSLog" in objective C have any release product overhead?

What would be the best equivalent of the if(D) logic above?

Right now I'm trying the

```
#ifdef macro
NSLog(@"%@",@"Some debug info");
#endif
```

Does this remove the code in question from the compilation unit?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300673/is-it-true-that-one-should-not-use-nslog-on-production-code/302246#302246

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, calls to `NSLog` have overhead.  Every call is a function call that formats a string and writes it somewhere.

Yes, the `#ifdef macro` removes the `NSLog` call entirely, if `macro` is not defined.

However, it might be simpler for you to do something like this:

```
// Use this to enable debug logging
#define D_NSLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)

// Use this to disable debug logging
#define D_NSLog(...) do {} while(0)
```

and use `D_NSLog` in place of `NSLog`.

Answer (score 0):

<del>`NSLog` does not have any release product overhead.</del> My fault/misconception here, I thought that by what he said he meant if he had to call `release` on it or not.

The best equivalent would probably be:

```
BOOL D = YES;

if (D)
{
    NSLog("Tag: %@", tag);
    NSLog("String: %@", string);
}
```

alernatively:

```
#define D YES

if (D)
{
    NSLog("Tag: %@", tag);
    NSLog("String: %@", string);
}
```

whichever way will work... if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: NSLog does not have overhead? Really?

Comment: Sometimes i have to put logging statements into very frequently iterated loops. This is why as a little performance boost, i'd like to remove the check for the boolean entirely. If I remember correctly, the java compiler upon seeing static const D = false; does not include or does not execute the code, because it can never be ran. By "release" I meant: does the NSLog even work in a release product? I thought that stuff like NSAssert was for debug only. Am I wrong here?