# How to do not write log on release mode in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, nslog

In my memory, there's some code that can let the `NSLog` not work when released.

I don't want to remove my `NSLog` in my code.It helps a lot on debug mode.

So I want to find a way that can leave them in my code, and also don't slow down the application when released.

Thanks for your help~~

Comment: check the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/nslog-tips-and-tricks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common way to remove all `NSLog(…)` call in a release is to create a macro that is between conditional preprocessor macro and compiles to nothing, something like this:

```
#ifdef RELEASE
# define NSLog(...) //remove loggin in production
#endif
```

Put this code in a `.h` file that is included in every other file, like a `Defines.h` that is `#include`'d in the prefix header (`.pch`).

`RELEASE` should be a preprocessor macro defined against the Release configuration in the "Build Settings" tab of your target.

[image: Apple LLVM compiler 4.0 - Preprocessing]

### Related Questions

- [Is it true that one should not use NSLog() on production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300673/is-it-true-that-one-should-not-use-nslog-on-production-code?lq=1)
- [How to print out the method name and line number and conditionally disable NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/nslog-tips-and-tricks)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to replace NSLog with a custom macro.

Put for instance

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#    define DLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#    define DLog(...) /* */
#endif
#define ALog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
```

in your prefix pch file.

Use ALog for cases where you always want log output regardless of the state of the debug flag, and DLog for log only in debug mode.

[Source](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/debugging/the-evolution-of-a-replacement-for-nslog)