# Misunderstanding of macros in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macros, header-files

There is something that I fundamentally don't understand because I cannot for the life of me get this to work. I want to create a macro that extends `NSLog(NSString *format, ...)`. Here is what I came up with:

NSLogExtensions.h

```
#define DebugLog(debugMode, format, ...) MyDebugLog(debugMode, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@> (Line %d): ", NSStringFromClass([self class]), __LINE__] stringByAppendingString:format], ##__VA_ARGS__)

@interface NSLogExtensions : NSObject

@end
```

NSLogExtensions.m

```
#import "NSLogExtensions.h"

@implementation NSLogExtensions

void MyDebugLog(bool debugMode, NSString *format, ...) {
    va_list(argumentList);
    va_start(argumentList, format);
    if (debugMode) {
        NSLogv(format, argumentList);
    }
    va_end(argumentList);
}

@end
```

I expected to be able to include the NSLogExtensions header file and then be able to use the macro, but I receive the GCC implicit function declaration warning still.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this? Turn off logging based on teh macro?

Comment: The main goal is to be able to turn on and off logging with a boolean that I can specify within each class. I also added line numbers and the class name to each log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DebugLog` macro uses the function `MyDebugLog`, therefore you must add the prototype

```
void MyDebugLog(bool debugMode, NSString *format, ...);
```

to *NSLogExtensions.h*. Then it compiles without warnings.

**BUT** your solution has one (in my opinion) great disadvantage compared to the solutions that @calvinBhai refers to: Even if you switch off logging by setting  `debugMode` to `false`, the `DebugLog` macro will evaluate all arguments and call `MyDebugLog`. With the other solutions, the preprocessor will remove everything if logging is disabled.

Comment: If I was worried about having logs in my production code, I would probably add a global flag as well. But for now I just want to be able to control what part of my project prints debug code when. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this answer

[Is it true that one should not use NSLog() on production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300673/is-it-true-that-one-should-not-use-nslog-on-production-code)

it has a lot more detail on how to go about using a macro for your extended NSLogs

Comment: My macro is almost exactly the same, but rather than using a single global macro to enable/disable logging, I want to pass it as a parameter.