# How to disable NSLog all over the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor, nslog

I want to disable `NSLog()` across all instances in an app.  I found some code that does that:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#define NSLog //
#endif
```

But adding this code to each file isn't good idea. How can I make it easier?

Comment: define it in .pch file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Xcode has a precompiled header file (`{project-name}-Prefix.pch` in the Supporting Files group by default) that is a great place to put code that will be used across every file in the project.  For going a step further and improving the log message itself, see [Is it true that one should not use NSLog() on production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300673/is-it-true-that-one-should-not-use-nslog-on-production-code?rq=1).

Answer (score 6):

Add the following lines to your constants file:

```
#define DEBUGGING NO    //or YES
#define NSLog if(DEBUGGING)NSLog
```

The two following sentences give the same results

```
#define NSLog
```

and

```
#define NSLog //
```

because all text that begin with // are deleted in a precompiling phase ("//" included)

Comment: your // suggestion is dangerous because you can spread NSLog over multiple lines. your if statement looks flaky too... you could use a scoped if and parameters for the NSLog macro to make it better...

Answer (score 2):

What I do is put this in the precompiled header file (*YourAppName.pch*):

```
#define MyLog if(0); else NSLog
```

Then I change all NSLog to MyLog everywhere else in the app. It works as if it were NSLog. But when you want to disable NSLog, go back to the *.pch* file and change the `0` to `1` and presto, all logging stops.

Comment: This is dangerous because it changes the binding of any subsequent `else`. I.e. `if (someCondition) MyLog(blah); else doSomething();` doesn't mean what it appears to.

Comment: @KenThomases Don't look at me, I got it from Jens Alfke! I haven't run into any issues like that yet, but I'm sure your warning is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

This will also take care of the warnings that arise when using

```
#define NSLog //
```

**The code:**

```
#ifndef DEBUG
  #define NSLog(...)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following lines when you do'"t need NSLOG to your constants file

```
#define NSLog                       //
```

and comment it when you need it.