# xcode 5 can't see NSLog(s) from old iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an older `iOS6` app that I was playing with last year;  it was only for my wife, so I never released it, but I wanted to dust it off and see if it was potentially useful to others. So I load it up in `XCode5` (5.0.2 running on 10.8.4; I've also tried this on my home laptop running the same `XCode and Mavericks`).  However, though the app builds and runs fine, none of my `NSLog` statements show up in the console, on either computer.  I've cleaned, rebuilt, run it on every simulator and iPad I have, hunted through settings, torn my hair out, etc., but I can't figure out how to get them to show up.  I started a new iOS app to make sure it's not something in my setup, but `NSLogs` from there work just fine.  Unfortunately, I'm not even sure where to start looking to fix this.  Does anyone have any ideas for directions that I should be exploring here?  Thanks!

Edit:  I just tried copying over the files into a new project, and now the `NSLogs` are showing up!  Still leaves me with no ideas as to why they're not showing up in the old project.

Edit2: It's not just user error;  I can see the log messages from the new project with the copied files (see image).  They just don't show in the old project when I run it.

[image: log screenshot]

Comment: Have you done something like this anywhere in your code...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002001/how-to-disable-nslog-all-over-the-app

Comment: Just checked, and no, I didn't.  Good thought, but it also doesn't explain why they would work when I copied over to a new project...?

Comment: Did you check the pch file? I wasn't sure whether you would have copied that along with your source.

Comment: *headdesk* *headdesk* *headdesk* *headdesk* Damn it, that was it.  There was some sort of NSLog debug hidden in the pch that I'd apparently gotten cute with before.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment by @combinatorial, I had a debug statement hidden (so cleverly that I fooled myself) in the pch file.  Thanks so much for helping me nail that down!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you're not opened a Console in XCode 5, it seems, you're trying see a logs in member console.

Try click at here and you will see console with "All Output" option:

[image]

Comment: No, I can see the logs in the copied project.  I've revised the question to highlight that.