# IOS/Xcode: Suppress NSLog Statements for Release in 2018

Tags: ios, xcode, nslog

Because NSLog statements slow down apps, it seems advisable to remove them prior to release. A number of [older answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002001/how-to-disable-nslog-all-over-the-app) going back to 2010 suggest putting some code in the pch file such as:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
   #define NSLog(...);
#endif
```

However, Xcode no longer automatically creates a pch file.  I gather it is possible to manually create a pch file but this seems like a bit of a kludge.  Is manually creating a pch file and adding the above code to it still the recommended way to comment out NSLog statements prior to release or is there a more modern approach?

Answer (score 2):

All the old answers I found (including adding a PCH file) didn't work for Swift. Here's what finally worked for me:

1. Define the DEBUG flag by adding **"-D DEBUG"** to **"Other Swift Flags"** in the build settings.
2. Add the following global code (I just put it in a file named Globals.swift):

> ```
> #if !DEBUG
> public func NSLog(_ format: String, _ args: CVarArg...) {
> }    
>
> public func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
> }
> #endif
> ```

Comment: Is it necessary to define DEBUG flag inside the "Other Swift Flags"? I have tested the `#if DEBUG` and so long the build configuration is set to Release in edit scheme, the code inside the  `#if DEBUG` will not get printed to console.

Answer (score 1):

It is still possible to create a pre-compiled header, however this is discouraged, at least by default. To do this, edit the build settings for your target, and define a path to a Prefix Header.

[image: Prefix Header]

**Use a Logging Library**

Perhaps you can use a logging library, like [CocoaLumberJack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack), or [here](https://github.com/appsquickly/OCLogTemplate) is a very simple one, that nonetheless works well.

Comment: If you already have a lot of NSLog statements in the code, would you recommend going the pch route?  Is that what people do?  I would imagine there are still many developers who use NSLog statements who need to remove them at release time....

Comment: Depends on reqs and what project is for, but generally recommend to use a logging lib over NSLog - can do things like log at 'info' level for release and trace for debug. You could do a search/replace to introduce a lib. Related discussion about pch files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24194968/404201

Comment: for the simple logger, do I have to import the library into every file where I have a log statement ie import "OCLogTemplate.h"?  And would I just rewrite all my NSLog ("name:%@ and id%d for item",_item.name,_item.id);statements as LogDebug("name:%@ and id%d for item",_item.name,_item.id);?

Comment: In the readme file, you say it is preferred to flip switches in build settings.  Can you provide an example of where to do this?