# NSLog bad in production. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300673/is-it-true-that-one-should-not-use-nslog-on-production-code) suggests that NSLog in production is a really bad idea. I'm trying to understand why. Here are some of my theories.

1. NSLog, logs only on the main_thread (UI Thread) hence even logging from other threads is a bad idea (A thread switch is involved).
2. NSLog, writes to a output stream, blocking the process entirely.

Can anyone tell me what other theories exist? Or if someone knows the exact solution.

Comment: Why you need NSLog in production version ? Also the reasons and solutions are there in the post you linked with your question.

Comment: @MidhunMP: I understand it takes resources, I'm trying to understand what resources.

Answer (score 0):

It's also a security liability. You don't want to expose details about payment transactions, balances..credit card numbers..or anything else that you are legal bound (by your clients) to not disclose.

Comment: In that case the advice would be "Don't NSLog sensitive data", not "Avoid NSLog in production"

Comment: You do not base your app's security (and legality) on human factor. Ever. Why? because this will fail extremely quickly either for negligence, honest error, or sabotage.